# LINQ group by "contains string"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have next Linq and I would like to group by c.RegisterId (string) starts with string. So for example I would like that all the next examples fall in the same group.

```
12345
1234500
123450


from c in _companyRepository.GetAll() 
group c by c.RegisterId into grpCompany 
select grpCompany
```

Comment: How do you define group? Is it `12345` or `123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = from c in _companyRepository.GetAll() 
          group c by c.RegisterId.Length <= 5 ? 
                     c.RegisterId : 
                     c.RegisterId.Substring(0, 5) into grpCompany 
          select grpCompany
```

You wanted grouping for the first 5 characters, right? :-)

I'll note that the query, being executed by the SQL, probably doesn't need the length check.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Hello', 1, 10000)
```

works always (returning `Hello`). This is different from .NET where `"Hello".Substring(0, 10000)` will explode, so probably

```
var res = from c in _companyRepository.GetAll() 
          group c by c.RegisterId.Substring(0, 5) into grpCompany 
          select grpCompany
```

is enough.

Comment: Ok thats cool. How about if I would like to use some similarity function like "Levenshtein distance" or something similar.

Comment: @JernejNovak You can't do funny things on an SQL Server (unless you implement your methods in SQLCLR). You could do it in local.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide how many letters from the left you want to consider the base common identifier (5 for instance).

```
from c in _companyRepository.GetAll() 
group c by c.RegisterId.Substring(0, 5) into grpCompany 
select grpCompany
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
_companyRepository.GetAll().GroupBy(x=>x.Substring(0,4));
```